# HAL_IncTick() not called anywhere

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, hal-library

Every time I use hal_delay() the program hangs just before the call to hal_delay().

I have gone through few comments where it is told to add HAL_IncTick() to SysTick_Handler in stm32f4xx_it.c file. However, I don't have any file with this name in my project. Can anyone please help as to where exactly I need to add HAL_IncTick() for it to increment uTick.

Comment: Where in your project do you have your interrupt handler functions? Do you have any interrupt handlers?

Comment: `grep -ir systick *` or the gui equivalent case insensitive search of your project tree

Comment: If you don't currently have any interrupt handlers of your own or an existing stm32f4xx_it.c file, you can either create that file and add a `void SysTick_Handler(void) { HAL_IncTick(); }` to it, or just add that to your main.c file.

Comment: If i write my own function void SysTick_handler(), i get redefinition error.  i have it in one of  the file named irq_cm4f.s  generated by cmsis. I also have it in EventRecorder.c file which is also generated by Keil run time environment. This one is disabled by macro in EventRecorder.h file. if i enable it, i again get redefinition error as it is in irq_cm4f.s file. Is there a way i can add HAL_IncTick in irq_cm4f.s file

Comment: I have interrupt handlers for specific modules defined in respective files, like interrupt handler for uart is in uart file, timer interrupt handler in timer file.  there is no specific file where all interrupts are defined.

Comment: Has anyone else faced the same issue ? If you have solution, please suggest something.

Comment: Would suggest you start a new project entirely and try to build it as is, without making any changes. If it builds, search for the SysTick handler definition and see how it's done.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem on an STM32G4 that drove me crazy for a couple of days. Hopefully my experience will be useful to someone else.

I followed all the usual advice about interrupt priority and all that, to no avail. I eventually realised that it was a HW problem in my case, as the same 2-line test code (toggle an LED; HAL_Delay(1000);) would work fine on an *almost* identical board.

Turns out I had pin PB8/BOOT0 pulled up quite strongly, as I was using its shared I2C function. The problem is that pulling up BOOT0 calls the bootloader, unless this is disabled from configuration bits. The inline debugger would not pick that up and run my code as 'normal' but apparently with interrupt priorities messed up.

All fixed as soon as I cleared nSWBOOT0 bit (leaving nBOOT0 set).

Comment: Had the same problem, HAL_IncTick didn't get called even if everything else seems to work just fine, replaced the HW and the problem is gone

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on "cleared nSWBOOT0 bit (leaving nBOOT0 set)"?

Comment: nSWBOOT0 and nBOOT0 are configuration bits that you can easily access using the STM32CubeProgrammer desktop application. They are not modified by flashing your code (unless you specifically write onto them from your code). 

nSWBOOT0 tells the MCU whether or not to read the BOOT0 pin at power up to run the bootloader; the content of nBOOT0 replaces the value of the BOOT0 pin, when nSWBOOT0 = 0.

Comment: To further clarify, the n prefix stands for negated, so the behavior of that bit is the opposite of what the name says. E.g., SWBOOT0=1 would mean use the software value of BOOT0 (rather than the hardware pin's value), but since the actual bit is called nSWBOOT0, you need to set it to 0 (clear it) to have that effect.

Confusing, but I hope it's clear!